Policing the LLQ in QoS
I am studying QoS for my ENCOR exam and my study resources mention LLQ and policing.
With LLQs, if we don’t define a policing limit, the LLQ could starve out the other queues if it’s constantly receiving a stream of VOIP packets, correct? What I don’t quite understand is that if you reserve, let’s say, 30% of BW for VOIP traffic and then you set a limit on it to not starve out the other queues, isn’t this the same as if you had just reserved less bandwidth for VOIP traffic instead? Since out of the original reservation, you’re still limiting it to a lower value.
That's all, thank you.

30 % is the minimum; policing sets the maximum.

So if I understand this correctly. If I was to reserve 30% for VOIP traffic, it would have this value guaranteed BUT it could use more if there were some other queues that weren't fully using their bandwidth? While with policing, we tell it that this is the maximum and that it should not to exceed this specific value?

Correct. If you get voice outside the 30%, and there gets to be congestion, then calls will get dropped from outside the 30%, and that is not good. It all depends on the specific needs of a site.

QoS only takes effect in the case of congestion, so any traffic class can use all the bandwidth (except in the case of policing), until there is congestion.
